# How to convert a string into datetime format

Tags: python, pandas, list, datetime, typeerror

I'm trying to convert strings in a list to datetime format on Python. I am unable to use `pd.DateTime` at the moment. The imported `datetime` package doesn't seem to work. I'm new to this.

Please help.

Cheers.

[Code Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JM8Cu.png)

Comment: Can you add the code directly to the question rather than an image, please?

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using official datetime formats

Example:

```
from datetime import datetime

#datetime(year, month, day)
date = datetime(2018, 11, 28)


# datetime(year, month, day, hour, minute, second, microsecond)
date = datetime(2017, 11, 28, 23, 55, 59, 342380)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `strptime`

```
from datetime import datetime, strptime

my_datetime_list = [strptime(string_date, '%y-%m-%d') for string_date in list_of_string_dates]
```